# Deduce $aN=xN$ from $a^{-1}x\in N$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

This is part of Exercise 2.4.7 of F. M. Goodman's *"Algebra: Abstract and Concrete"*.

> **Exercise 2.4.7:** Let $\phi: G\to H$ be a homomorphism of groups with kernel $N$. For $a, x\in G$, show that
>
> $$a^{-1}x\in N\,\,\,\text{implies}\,\,\, aN= xN.$$ Here $aN=\{an\mid n\in N\}$.

### My Attempt:

Suppose $a^{-1}x\in N$. Then $x=aa^{-1}x\in aN$ implies $xN\subseteq aN$.

How do I show that $aN\subseteq xN$?

Comment: It's probably something simple but the answer has alluded me these last few hours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $N$ is a subgroup you also have $x^{-1}a=(a^{-1}x)^{-1}\in N$.

Comment: Ah, of course! Thank you.

Comment: Then $a=xx^{-1}a\in xN$ gives $aN\subseteq xN$.